# how to set up yScale in dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am newbie with dc.js. I want to set up the yScale between two values. I had no problem to set yScale with D3 but it seems more complicated with dc.js. In the documentation I didn't find anything.
I tried:

.y(d3.scaleLinear().range([minY,maxY])) or
.y(d3.scaleLinear().domain([minY,maxY])) without success

Thank you for your help.

My code:

```
// Parse the date / time
const dateFormatSpecifier = "%Y-%m-%d";
const dateFormat = d3.timeFormat(dateFormatSpecifier);
const dateFormatParser = d3.timeParse(dateFormatSpecifier);
const numberFormat = d3.format('.2f');



 // Get the data
d3.json("{% url "fund:block_time_analysis" asset_id %}").then(function(data){
    console.log(data)

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = dateFormatParser(d.date);
      d.close = +d.close;
      d.open = +d.open;
      d.aum = +d.aum;
      d.valueBchk = +d.valueBchk;
      d.valueIdx = +d.valueIdx;
    });
// not very proud of this part but I don't find another way
const minfd = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.close; });
const minbchk = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.valueBchk; });
const minidx = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.valueIdx; });
const minY = d3.min([minfd, minbchk, minidx]);

const maxfd = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; });
const maxbchk = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.valueBchk; });
const maxidx = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.valueIdx; });
const maxY = d3.min([maxfd, maxbchk, maxidx]);

const ndx = crossfilter(data)

// Create chart objects
var cumulativeChart = dc.compositeChart("{{ id_chart }}");

var dateDim = ndx.dimension(d => d.date);



var fdValue = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {return d.close; });
var bchkValue = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {return d.valueBchk; });
var idxValue = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {return d.valueIdx; });

let xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([dateDim.bottom(1)[0].date, dateDim.top(1)[0].date])
let yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([minY, maxY])


cumulativeChart.width(width_block1)
    .height(height_ts_block1)
    .margins(margin_ts_block1)
    .dimension(dateDim)
    .transitionDuration(500)
    .elasticY(true)
    .brushOn(true)
    .valueAccessor(function (d) { return d.value})
    .title(function (d) {return  d.key;})
    .x(xScale).xUnits(d3.timeDays)
    .y(yScale)
    .compose([
        dc.lineChart(cumulativeChart).group(fdValue),
        dc.lineChart(cumulativeChart).group(bchkValue),
        dc.lineChart(cumulativeChart).group(idxValue)
    ])

dc.renderAll();

});
```

Comment: Please spell out the expected and actual behavior. What result do you get, a blank chart or an error? Or the wrong domain? If you set `elasticY(true)` then the chart will automatically set the domain for you, cancelling your attempt to set it. Usually you don't want to set the range (the chart will do that for you).

Comment: Hi Gordon, Actually you gave the solution to my problem.  When I set elasticY on false, the chart set the domain correctly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great! Yep, that’s what that parameter does...